# Creating a Singleton class rather than Injecting repository in constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

Vaadin views only allows injecting @Autowired repositories in constructor, but instead of doing that I implemented it using a Singleton class. my question is, do I have to worry in the future about this? or will it affect my app or are there going to be some performance issues?

How to implement in Vaadin view:

```
public class HelloWorldView extends HorizontalLayout {

    public HelloWorldView(@Autowired AccountRepository accountRepository) {
   
        for(Account a : accountRepository.findAll()){
             System.out.println(a.getName);  
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
public class HelloWorldView extends HorizontalLayout {

    @Autowired
    public HelloWorldView(AccountRepository accountRepository) {

        for(Account a : accountRepository.findAll()){
             System.out.println(a.getName);  
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid passing a parameter in a view class of Vaadin, so my implementation is:

```
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {
}

@Service
public class AccountService {

    private static AccountRepository accountRepository;

    private static AccountService INSTANCE;

    private AccountService(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        this.accountRepository = accountRepository;
    }

    public synchronized static AccountService getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = new AccountService(accountRepository);
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public List<Account> findAll() {
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }
}

public class HelloWorldView extends HorizontalLayout {

    public HelloWorldView() {
   
        for(Account a : AccountService.getInstance().findAll()){
             System.out.println(a.getName);  
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

remove the static from the findAll() method and call the service using AccountService.getInstance().findAll()

Comment: Using static variable in conjuction to the Spring Bean is not advice, because we can't make sure the object is injected by Spring before the static function is called, but if you are sure that the variable is always initiated then I have nothing else stopping you. 
Spring Bean is instantiated with singleton object design pattern unless specified different, I'm not sure about what you want, creating autowired constructor looks fine for me, if you want something else you can also autowired by setter injection through setter function.

Comment: I just want to have a different approach on how to implement it but I'm just worried that there might be some performance issues later on that's why I have posted it here to get some feedback before proceeding..

Comment: I do not see any issue with either of both your approach unless the static reference, and also if you want another approach you can check the setter injection style, it uses autowired annotation on a function that sets the value of the variable you want, and then the Spring framework will inject the appropriate object to the variable.

Comment: My 2ct: when in rome... If you have decided to use Spring, then use it the intended way. If you are asking this, because some button down many many layouts and classes needs this service, then you might want to rething your architecture. A button should not need a repository, it should set the wheels in motion for some central building block to use it (just an example of course).

Comment: What is the problem you're actually trying to solve? In other words, why are you "trying to avoid passing a parameter in a view class of Vaadin"?

Comment: Hi @ollitietavainen I was not trying to solve a problem, I was just trying to implement a different approach..

Comment: As @cfrick Use the tools/frameworks as they are intended to use

Comment: @garagumo I assume there's still a reason why you're trying to avoid passing a parameter for the view class. If you start with that reason, you might get better results.

Comment: I think I'll just stick to the standard as you've all suggested. Thank you :)